# what happen on the copper coil on Motor 3 phase till follow the running momentum when stop supply power?

Tags: circuit-analysis

what happen on the copper coil on Motor 3 phase till follow the running momentum when stop supply power ??? it will make the copper wire coil damaged or burn ????

---

Please decide if this is what you are asking :

A 3 phase motor

- is operating normally and then
- power is removed, and
- the momentum of a connected rotating load causes the motor to continue revolving,

Is the motor likely to be damaged by doing this.?

Comment: Even guessing *What will happen to the copper windings of a 3-phase motor* and *when cutting off supply power* I cannot understand *till follow the running momentum*. Have you tried having the entire sentence translated back from English?

Comment: Sorry make y missing understand, i mean during the 3 phase  motor running and we stop supply power. we can see the motor will have running with low speed and will be stop. during that time, what happen the coil copper wire inside motor ??? the burn - circuit phase  will be happen ??? thanks.

Comment: I see - at the instance power is cut, it will have a certain speed. If the load doesn't vary and it has been running as a motor, it will slow down and eventually stop - sooner with a high load than a low one. Shorting out the motor terminals is too crude to consider implementing.

Comment: Suggestion:  Translating into English --> This sounds complicated. It's not. I can explain better if its seems useful. I used to have to comminicate with people in China but I do not speak Chinese. SO I used Google translate backwards and forwards, adjusting my text, until the retranslation stayed about the same.

Comment: If motor has no electrical connection it should slow down and stop with no damage. If you apply a load to the terminals it will stop more quickly. Usually no electrical damage. The hard braking MAY cause mechanical damage in some cases.

Comment: Please look at my addition to your question. Is that what you wanted to know?